# Creating a branch and not seeing changes in another non-master branch

Tags: git

Let's say I make changes to some code in a branch. However, at the same time, developer B makes some changes too, in a seperate branch. Developer B's change is to change a variable from 2 to 3.

However, in my branch, where I've done a pull, I PR my branch, and I don't see this change, despite having done the pull. Instead, I see the old code.

I fixed this by doing a pull from his branch into master, and then a branch I made which pulled from master. However, is this correct or is there a better way?

EDIT:

Developer A:

1. Creates branch, call it branch-a
2. Modified code in this branch
3. Creates a PR to merge to master

The code is to change some variables, e.g. 2 to 3.

Meanwhile, I:

1. Create a branch
2. Write some (unrelated) code
3. Create a PR branch

This is terraform code, so when a plan runs, I don't see the change of 2 to 3 in the plan (no change).

This was fixed by doing a pull in master, and then creating a branch and doing a pull immediately. But the pull I did was from his branch.

Comment: It's hard to decipher that actual steps you took based on your language.  If you can more clearly list out all steps you took, maybe someone can venture an answer here.

Comment: Git isn't really about *branches*, but rather *commits*. `git pull` runs `git fetch` and then `git merge`: `git fetch` is about getting commits, and `git merge` is ... um, complicated. :-) But it can use the commits obtained by the fetch step. Which commits it uses, and how, depend on the arguments you gave to `git pull`. We'd definitely need more specifics here.

Comment: Hey guys, see my edit.

Comment: if it works, it is the "good way". Unless you have policies regarding code standards that state otherwise. In general, you might have defaulted merge conflicts solve method to keep your code instead of theirs code. Or a thousand other things. Why did you say you pulled [the other dev's branch] and PullRequest your own branch? You pulled, what are you requesting to pull again? Did you pull your old code on top of the new code?